# how to redirect a url with port via htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, htaccess

Im Trying to Redirect a Single url

like http://tracker.niresh.co:12495/announce to http://tracker.niresh.co/announce.php

How can i get it working through htaccess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 12495
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/announce 
RewriteRule (.*) http://tracker.niresh.co/announce.php
```

Comment: I have applied the code but doesnt seems to be working

Comment: @user1862521 `mod_rewrite` has to be enabled on the server for that to work. Try executing `a2enmod rewrite` (as root) and restarting Apache afterwards.